# Fetch data from PostgreSQL database for iOS

Tags: ios, postgresql

I'm having an iOS app to which I need to pull certain data from a 3rd party site. They do not provide an API, rather they provide their PostgreSQL database which is accessible via cloud. How shall I fetch data from the DB in this scenario? I've limited experience in backend technologies to develop a custom API. How to link the database provided by the vendor if I'm planning to go with a custom API?

Comment: They allow outside connections directly to their database?

Comment: Yes. They gave username, password, port number etc. and I was able to perform query using postgresql client from my system